# Postgres WAL file not getting deleted

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I've got the following command for archive

```
archive_command = 'rsync -av %p /home/archive/%f'
```

We clean files from there.

But the problem is that after the file has been copied to the archive folder, it is not deleted from `/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_xlog`.

I don't see any error in Postgres logs.
This is Postgres 9.6 with one master one standby configuration.

Additionally it would helpful to know the procedure to delete these old WAL files once they are processed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several reasons why WAL files don't get removed from `pg_xlog`:

- `max_wal_size` is set higher than the amount of WAL in `pg_xlog`.
- `wal_keep_segments` is set higher than the number of WAL files in `pg_xlog`.
- There is a replication slot at a WAL location older than the WAL files.

To find out about the replication slots, try the following query:

```
SELECT slot_name,
       lpad((pg_control_checkpoint()).timeline_id::text, 8, '0') ||
       lpad(split_part(restart_lsn::text, '/', 1), 8, '0') ||
       lpad(substr(split_part(restart_lsn::text, '/', 2), 1, 2), 8, '0')
       AS wal_file
FROM pg_replication_slots;
```

This will give you the name of the oldest WAL file each replication slot still needs.

Comment: Yes I was able to figure that out, thanks for your reply though. I forgot to update the thread. In our case wal_keep_segments was set to high and hence files were not moved. We reduce the setting value and reloaded the configuration, after that old WAL files were moved to archive.

Comment: You can use `pg_xlogfile_name(restart_lsn)` or starting with version 10 `pg_walfile_name(restart_lsn)`. But AFAIK you can use this function in master only.

Comment: @SahapAsci Yes, you can do that. But what is the connection to the question or answer?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , To get oldest wal file, I use this query which I think is more catchy. `SELECT slot_name, pg_walfile_name(restart_lsn) AS wal_file FROM pg_replication_slots;`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe. So I run the query and see that there are slots that need the WAL files. All of my data is up to date with my logical replica. How can I find what needs to be done so the WAL files can be archived?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I've drop the oldest replication slot and postgres cleaned up pg_xlog.

```
postgres=# SELECT slot_name,
   lpad((pg_control_checkpoint()).timeline_id::text, 8, '0') ||
   lpad(split_part(restart_lsn::text, '/', 1), 8, '0') ||
   lpad(substr(split_part(restart_lsn::text, '/', 2), 1, 2), 8, '0')
   AS wal_file
FROM pg_replication_slots;
slot_name |         wal_file
-----------+--------------------------
 postgres2 | 0000000100000000000000B0
(1 row)

postgres=# select pg_drop_replication_slot('postgres2');
 pg_drop_replication_slot
--------------------------

(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks, man, it fixed my issue. In Postgres 9.5, the pg_control_checkpoint does not exist, so I just run the pg_drop_replication_slot command anyway, and it works.